# Breadcrumbs are not appearing because they are null

Tags: php, magento, breadcrumbs

I am trying to move the breadcrumbs to inside a category page, and Ive been struggling. I have been looking at the following resources, but they have not helped:

- http://forum.azmagento.com/magento-users-guide/breadcrumbs-are-not-showing-in-magento-cms-pages-745.html
- http://www.magenshop.com/how-to/breadcrumbs-right-of-category-name.html

I have added the following to remove the breadcrumbs from `root` and then add them as a child of `category.products`. Like so:

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
    <reference name="root">
        <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="category.products">
        <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="onlybreadcrumbs" as="onlybreadcrumbs" template="page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

This is at the top of catalog/category/view.phtml I am adding the breadcrumbs file with this:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('onlybreadcrumbs')->toHtml(); ?>
```

At the top of page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml I have this:

```
<pre>Crumbs:<?php var_dump($crumbs); ?></pre>
```

The output at the top of a category pages is this:

```
Crumbs:NULL
```

My problem here is that after moving the breadcrumbs into the category view file, the `$crumbs` variable is `NULL`, and as a result none of the breadcrumbs appear.

---

In the end I used code from this page to get around the problem: http://awebtech.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/magento-add-breadcrumbs-in-pages-where.html

However this solution is basically to just rebuild the breadcrumbs from scratch, and it feels like a bit of a hack.

Can someone explain to me, after moving the breadcrumbs into another file, why `$crumbs` is now `NULL` - and most importantly, how to fix this issue properly.